# PubSub Post Authentications Broken?

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

In our current architecture we have devised a means for testing our non-production application by streaming events over from Pub/Sub with live data; this non-production application is isolated in a separate google cloud project to the production application. The live data is only fed into the Pub/Sub topics in our production application.

We have designed an approach that will create a subscription to the production topic and use a push method to publish the data into Pub/Sub in the non-production project. I have tested this inside the same account successfully using the URL:
`https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project_id}/topics/{topic_id}:publish`

To post/publish into another projects pubsubs topic the only option seems to be enable authentication, this should let you assign a service account which can be used to provide the authentication header in the POST, though I have not so far been able to get this working at all and think there might be an issue with the feature.

When it came to implementing this across project, I started out giving the default PubSub google managed service account in production permissions to publish into the non-production topic. This did not work and I receive errors in the subscription metrics. After digging a little deeper I noticed that Pub/Sub has an option to enable authentication; this supposedly lets you use a service account in the POST request through JWT's.

From here I created a service account in the production project, with permissions to publish in the other project. Then granted permissions for the pub/sub service account to create a token as the docs describe (roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator / iam.serviceAccounts.getOpenIdToken). This was also ultimately unsuccessful and resulted in no published messaged being sent to the non-production account.

I then created a concept environment where I could take testing a little further, I started logging the messages that were coming from Pub/Sub using a private endpoint and found the authorization header with Bearer `<token>`. From analyzing the token using jwt.io I found that it was valid for an hour allowing me time to try and publish to the other topic myself using curl. When doing this I get the following error:
`{ "error": { "code": 401, "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.", "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED" } }`
I decided to create a JWT OIDC token myself to see what all the fuss was about. This was pretty simple with a Python script using pyjwt and creating a service account key to sign the token with. I could then successfully use my created token to send a post request to pubsub. When comparing my decoded token with the one in the pubsub message I found a miss match on the "sub" data. This is set to indicate who the token refers to and on my successful token it refers to the service account email, however on the pubsub token it refers to the service accounts OAuth 2 Client ID. When setting my script to use the Client ID as the subject and using the token I receive the exact same 401 error as I'm getting with the pubsub token. This leads me to believe Google Cloud is sending the wrong subject in the JWT that Pub Sub creates rendering it unable to provide authentication.

For now, the only solution I have is allowing allAuthenticatedUsers to be able to publish on the topic and then immediately deleting this member after we are done with live data testing in non-production. There are of course methods outside of pubsub like the dataflow pubsub to pubsub template or creating a cloud function to pass on the message; but both of these add on needless complexity and expense from something that is supposedly possible in the pubsub service itself.

Comment: Do you use an access token or an identity token (JWT)? In addition, are you sure to have the correct permission set?

Comment: Hi guillaume, the pub/sub authentication uses a JWT, when I was testing out creating a manual JWT I did this using a Service Account key to sign the token. I have followed permissions according to docs but also had given it overly permissive roles in both projects just to check whether anything was missing :)

Comment: Do you have piece of code of how do you forge your token?

Comment: imports...
iat = time.time()
exp = iat + 3600

with open('sa-key.json') as saKeyFile:
  saKey = json.load(saKeyFile)

payload = {
  'iss': 'testserviceaccountpubsub@sensetive-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
  'sub': saKey['client_email'],
  'aud': 'https://pubsub.googleapis.com/',
  'iat': iat,
  'exp': exp
}

additional_headers = {'kid': saKey["private_key_id"]}
signed_jwt = jwt.encode(
  payload, saKey["private_key"], 
  headers=additional_headers,
  algorithm='RS256'
)
print(f"Signed JSON Web Token: {signed_jwt}")

Comment: You can't use self signed token. That's your mistake. You need to use a Google Cloud Signature, or use the Google Cloud client libraries that do that for you!

Comment: Sorry I think you might be mistaken. I'm not using that token it was just a test to see what the issue was with the pub/sub token. The pub/sub service itself is creating and signing the token.